# Correct installation of OmniThreadLibrary

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, omnithreadlibrary

I want to use OmniThreadLibrary in a project I am working on Delphi XE2, I've followed the instructions.

- Add OTL folder and OTL/src to Delphi's Library Path.
- Build both project in Delphi XE2 package and install.

The instructions are pretty simple and the OmniEventMonitor is in the palette.

However, I can not run a single one of the examples.

For example, when i try to run:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Button1.Enabled := false;

  Parallel.Async(
    procedure
    begin
      // executed in background thread
      Sleep(500);
      MessageBeep($FFFFFFFF);
    end,

    Parallel.TaskConfig.OnTerminated(
      procedure (const task: IOmniTaskControl)
      begin
      // executed in main thread
      btnAsync.Enabled := true;
    end
    )
  );
end;
```

I get the error **Undeclared Identifier Parallel**.

Did I do something wrong during the installation?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is:

> Undeclared Identifier Parallel.

`Parallel` is a class (containing class methods) declared in the `OtlParallel` unit. Which means that if the compiler cannot see the `Parallel` class, then you have not added `OtlParallel` to your uses clause.